# Java - ler XML de uma URL

Tags: java, xml, arquivo, jdom

Tenho uma função que lê XML e ela funciona 100%, o problema é que quando tento ler um XML que está online no meu servidor eu não consigo.

Segue  código:

```
public int lerXml() throws JDOMException, IOException, URISyntaxException {
    URL url = new URL("http://br728.teste.website/~ayzac296/smh/xml.xml");
    File f = new File(url.toURI());
    SAXBuilder sb = new SAXBuilder();
    Document d;
    try {
        d = sb.build(f);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return 0;
    }
    Element mural = d.getRootElement();
    List elements = mural.getChildren();
    Iterator i = elements.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Element element = (Element) i.next();
        if (Double.parseDouble(element.getChildText("tempo")) >= mediaPlayer.getCurrentTime().toSeconds()) {
            //System.out.println("Nome:" + element.getChildText("nome"));
            //System.out.println("Tempo:" + element.getChildText("tempo"));
            System.out.println("Menssagem:" + element.getChildText("conteudo"));
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Ele está mostrando o seguinte erro:

> Exception in thread "Thread-179" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI scheme is not "file"

Estou com dificuldade em transformar a URL em File.

Obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa de uma conexão http para baixar coisas vindas do http. Vou dar uma resposta explicando melhor isso já já

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode simplesmente passar sua URL para o *SAXBuilder*. Assim:

```
d = sb.build(url);
```

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado!